# CSS grid - making 2 divs with different widths responsive

Tags: html, css

I wonder if it is possible to make 2 columns responsive with css grid without using media queries. I have 2 div elements, one on the right side should take minimum `400px`, if it is not possible, then it should go in to the next row, and the left column should have the rest of the width. I wonder how should I do that?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-div"></div>
  <div class="right-div"></div>
</div>
```

**Css** that I have so far:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(60%, 100%) minmax(0, 400px);
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
}
```

But, that is not helping, how can I achieve wrapping of the column in to new row?

Comment: No there is no "wrapping" like that with CSS Grid.

Comment: ..and what is wrong with media queries...?